# How do you add incrementing numbers to the end of a command for a for loop?

Tags: c#

Because of the different processes, I would like to add a different number for each process group. I thought this syntax would work to have each loop for [i] to be for example a group of newProcessInfo1, newProcessInfo2, newProcessInfo3, ....

```
string output = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < strings.Count(); i++)
{
    var newProcessInfo[i] = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    newProcessInfo[i].FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
    newProcessInfo[i].WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    newProcessInfo[i].Verb = "runas";

    newProcessInfo[i].Arguments += @"-executionpolicy unrestricted -Command " + strings[i];
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(newProcessInfo[i]);

}
```

Comment: What you exactly want to do, Please explain in detail and also what you have tried so far?

Comment: As you know that `for loop` is self incremented based on your `strings.Count()` with `i++`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32222247/2613020 may help you

Comment: I had a problem with the newProcessInfo once before that if I didn't change it's name slightly for each loop that for some reason c# wouldn't run the commands.  Seemed odd when it happened but that has an effect on it (keeping the name the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for an Array; something like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo[] arrayProcessInfo= new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo[strings.Count()];
```

So that you can Add them like the following:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strings.Count(); i++)
{
    arrayProcessInfo[i] = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    arrayProcessInfo[i].FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
    arrayProcessInfo[i].WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    arrayProcessInfo[i].Verb = "runas";
    arrayProcessInfo[i].Arguments += @"-executionpolicy unrestricted -Command " + strings[i];
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(arrayProcessInfo[i]);
}
```

It will initially Create an array of `ProcessStartInfo`, contains `strings.Count()` indices. And Later by looping you can Create new ProcessStartInfo to each array index;

Alternatively you can use `List<ProcessStartInfo>` but i prefer Array since the Collection will have Predefined Boundries(`strings.Count()`).

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this to achieve the same,

```
Dictionary<int, System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo> incrementalArray = new Dictionary<int, System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo>(); ;
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    incrementalArray.Add(i, null);
}
```

**Then take values from the List to make the change**

```
string output = string.Empty;
for (int i = 0; i < strings.Count(); i++)
{
   incrementalArray[i] = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
   incrementalArray[i].FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
   incrementalArray[i].WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
   incrementalArray[i].Verb = "runas";

   incrementalArray[i].Arguments += @"-executionpolicy unrestricted -Command " + strings[i];
   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(incrementalArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think you can use for Indexed based names.

```
Dictionary<string, System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo> p = new Dictionary<string, System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo>(); ;
string pName = "newProcessInfo";
for (int i = 1; i <= strings.Count(); i++)
{
    string indexedProcess = pName + i.ToString();
    p.Add(indexedProcess, new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo());
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo pInfo = p(indexedProcess);
    pInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe";
    pInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    pInfo.Verb = "runas";
    pInfo.Arguments += @"-executionpolicy unrestricted -Command " + strings[i];
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(pInfo);
}
```

Now You can access your processInfo as `p("newProcessInfo1")`, p("newProcessInfo2") , etc. or as `p("newProcessInfo" + i.ToString())`, where `i` has integer value.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!